# Which one to use tf.layers or tf.keras.layers for high level OO code in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow have seemingly similar packages: tf.layers and tf.keras.layers. Which one is preferrable? It seems that tf.keras.layers extends tf.layers.

Comment: If you're concerned purely with the OO layers then there isn't much of a difference. TF nudges you in the direction of the functional calls `tf.layers.dense` instead of `tf.layers.Dense`; however, it is trivial to use the OO version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially the same, and it doesn't matter which one you use. The `tf.keras.layers` layers have guaranteed compatibility with the keras API, but that's the only difference.